# How to fetch parent div id with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, parent

I have the following html divs. I am populating the whole representation in a loop, Which means i might have a set of these divs. I want to toggle div "chart" and div "contact-layer". But when i do that it does not toggle the exact div i try to toggle but the first one, because i can't differentiate the divs as they all have the same class names except the very first div. i.e goal1, goal2, goal3, etc.

Now i want to fetch the id of the very first div which varies for every representation. 
I know that to fetch the parent div id i can use

```
$(this).parents('div').attr('id');
```

But i don't know how to fetch the very first div in this case, so i can get the exact div under the very first div.

```
<div id="goal1">
<div class="goal-parent">
            <div class="goal">

                <div id="top-layer">

                    <div id="component">
                        <select class="component-select">
                            <option id="one">WEBINAR SIGN-UPS</option>
                            <option id="one">WEBINAR SIGN-UPSwwewewew</option>
                            <option id="one">WEBINAR SIGN-UPS</option>
                            <option id="one">WEBINAR SIGN-UPS</option>
                            <option id="one">WEBINAR SIGN-UPS</option>
                        </select>
                        <span id="width_tmp"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="period">
                        <select class="period-select">
                            <option>Weekly</option>
                            <option>Daily</option>
                            <option>Quarterly</option>
                            <option>Six months</option>
                            <option>Yearly</option>
                        </select>
                        <span id="width_tmp"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>

                </div>

                <div id="second-layer">
                    <div id="count">14 544</div>
                    <div id="trend"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-2x"></i></div>
                    <div id="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="third-layer">
                    <div id="avarage">avarage: 16 345</div>
                    <div id="target">target: 20 000</div>
                </div>

                <div id="chart">

                </div>

                <div id="bottom-layer">

                    <div id="romi">ROMI: $30.543</div>

                    <div id="toggle-chart">
                        <div class="icon-chart"><i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-lg"></i></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="toggle-contact">
                        <div class="icon-contact"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg" ></i></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div id="contact-layer">

                    <div id="haeder-layer">
                        <div id="title-one">Contact</div>
                        <div id="title-two">Last visit</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="contacts">
                        <div id="contact-name"> <img src="<?=APP_URL?>corporate/images/icons/ix_op_all/16x16/plain/user1.png" class="navicon">
                            <a href=""> KlausTrolle, Follow-Up Systems AB</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="contact-visit"> 2 days ago</div>
                        <div id="contact-name"> <img src="<?=APP_URL?>corporate/images/icons/ix_op_all/16x16/plain/user1.png" class="navicon">
                            <a href=""> KlausTrolle, Follow-Up Systems AB</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="contact-visit"> 2 days ago</div>
                        <div id="contact-name"> <img src="<?=APP_URL?>corporate/images/icons/ix_op_all/16x16/plain/user1.png" class="navicon">
                            <a href=""> KlausTrolle, Follow-Up Systems AB</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="contact-visit"> 2 days ago</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="show-all">SHOW ALL CONTACTS</div>
                    <div id="bottom-line"></div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
$(this).closest('div').attr('id');
```

> ### [`.closest( selector ) Returns: jQuery`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
>
> **Description**: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

This will return the *closest* `div` element which is one of the element parents.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ELEMENT').parent().attr('id');
```

Comment: always include a description along with your code. [answer]

Answer (score 0):

As I know `$(element).parents('div')` will bring you the parents in their hierarchical stack, thus you can make  `$(element).parents('div').last()` in order to get the first div.
However if you would like to be more accurate you should use: `compareDocumentPosition` native javascript property. You could do this like:

```
var arr=$.makeArray($(element).parents('div'));

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
                    if (a === b) return 0;
                    if (!a.compareDocumentPosition) {
                        // support for IE8 and below
                        return a.sourceIndex - b.sourceIndex;
                    }
                    if (a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 2) {
                        // b comes before a
                        return 1;
                    }
                    return -1;
                });
var topElement=arr[0]
```

This will give you top element from your search criteria.
Hopes this will help you.